# Stationary point of Lagrangian

Tags: systems-of-equations, lagrange-multiplier

The situation:

Optimise $f(x,y)=x+y^2$

subject to $x^3+3x^2y^2+3y^4=7$.

I write the Lagrangian as $L(x,y,\lambda)=x+y^2-\lambda(x^3+3x^2y^2+3y^4-7)$ and partially differentiate each variable:

$L'_x(x,y,\lambda)=1-3\lambda x^2-6\lambda x y^2$

$L'_y(x,y,\lambda)=2y-6\lambda x^2y-12\lambda y^3$

$L'_\lambda(x,y,\lambda)=-(x^3+3x^2y^2+3y^4-7)$

which gives me the system:

1)  $1-3\lambda x^2-6\lambda x y^2=0$

2) $2y-6\lambda x^2y-12\lambda y^3=0 \Rightarrow 1-3\lambda x^2-6\lambda  y^2=0$

3) $-x^3-3x^2y^2-3y^4+7=0$

Then I equate equation 1) and 2) which solves for $x=1$. Plugging $x=1$ back into equation 3) gives me $y=1$ or $y=-1$.

The question is, how can the Lagrangian have 3 stationary points in this case? it should be evident that without solving for $\lambda$ that I only get two stationary points:

$(1,1,\lambda)$ and $(1,-1,\lambda)$

Yet, there should be three stationary points, what do I miss?

Comment: You removed a factor of $y$, Was there some reason to exclude $y=0$?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? If I insert $x=1$ into the third formula I eventually get $y^2+y^4 - 2=0$.

Comment: In equation $2$, you removed a factor of $y$. Why?

Comment: I am fairly new to systems of multivariate equations, I simply thought I could divide equation 2) by $2y$ in order to make the elimination process in the next step easier. Is that fundamentally wrong?

Comment: Yes, it's wrong unless you know $y\ne 0$. The factor of $y$ yields two cases. In one case, you have $y=0$. In the other case, you have the other factor is zero. By removing the factor of $y$, you lost a case.

Comment: Simplifying by y means dividing by y. You can not if $y!=0$.

Comment: As a simple example, suppose you have the equation $x^2=3x$. If you divide by $x$, you lose a solution.

Comment: The correct way to deal with equation $2$ is to factor it, and split the equation into two separate equations. The principle is basic: $ab=0$ if and only if $a=0$ or $b=0$.

Comment: Okay then there is my misunderstanding. Just to clarify, my professor gave an example with: 1) $8-4\lambda \sqrt L = 0$,  2) $8-2\lambda \frac{K}{\sqrt L} = 0$ in which he multiplies the first one by K and the second one with L. How is that any different compared to what I did? Thank you for pointing it out! Just now I want to know which "simplifications" are possible and which not.

Comment: Multiplying or dividing by a nonzero quantity doesn't gain or lose solutions. From equation $2$, it's clear that $K$ and $L$ are nonzero.

Comment: And how do we know that K and L are nonzero as opposed to $y$ or is that only possible because my professor knew beforehand?

Comment: the equation system is not so easy to solve, i think it is better to solve $x^3+3x^2y^2+3y^4=7$ for $y$ and to substitute this in the objective function

Comment: You can add to or subtract from both sides, without affecting the solution set. You can multiply and divide both sides by a nonzero quantity. More generally, you can apply an injective function to both sides (e.g., cube both sides). Multiplying both sides by an expression that might be zero can potentially introduce extraneous solutions, so if you choose to do that (sometimes you have to), you need to check the solutions at the end to make sure they're valid. Divding both sides by an expression that might be zero can lose solutions, so instead of dividing, just use the factor principle.

Comment: For the professor's equations, substitute $K=0$ in equation $2$. What does that yield? Similarly, what happens if $L=0$ in equation $1$ or $2$?